# executing DynamoDB, jetty exception error

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-dynamodb

so i Installed the local version of dynamoDB
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html .

And after that, executed the command is mentioned in the same link

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
```

the thing is i get this error every time

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/AbstractHandler
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

how do i get rid of this problem ?

**Using Ubuntu 16.04, trying to make dynamoDB work for nodeJS**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using this for local development, I'd highly suggest using a docker image for dynamoDB - this will ensure that you don't need specific configuration on your linux flavor and it should work out of the box.

For me, https://hub.docker.com/r/dwmkerr/dynamodb/ does work quite well for my use case. If you don't have docker yet, here's a handy guide on how to install it for Ubuntu 16.04 - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice, i'm trying it right now !